# Encountering Aquifers in an embark that claims to have no Aquifers

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have been having this problem, where 90% of the time, My fort gets water/mud everywhere, even though the Embark claims to have no Aquifer! No matter how many worlds I create, or what biome I embark in, I encounter an Aquifer on the **second** layer below the surface, and my fort floods(I think it is always salt-water too. Because I cannot designate it as a water source).

> And if I dig into a cavern to drain the water, It does drain. But it leaves a small amount (1/7) that **Never** evaporates. Years have passed, and there is no evaporation.

Comment: Are you sure you're not embarking in a location with multiple biomes? It's entirely possible for part of the map to have an aquifer and other parts to be free of it.

Comment: This happens when I the whole embark is the same biome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that DFhack's Embark Tools are the only reliable way to avoid Aquifers, because even if Neither of the biomes claim to have an Aquifer. Their still could be one